Laravel mock subscriber injection
I have a ShopSubscriber, registered in a service provider like this:
/** @var array<class-string> */
protected $subscribe = [
    ShopSubscriber::class,
];

This subscriber injects other dependencies through the constructor:
public function __construct(private Durable $durable)
{
}

And later on, it uses that dependency:
private function onShopSaved(ShopSaved $event): void
{
    $shop = $event->getShop();

    StartEvent::runAsync(
        $this->durable,
        $product,
        $shop
    );
}

Everything is good so far, but I don't know how to test it. I have a DurableStub class for tests, and in the test case setUp method, I have:
protected function setUp(): void
{
    parent::setUp();

    $this->durable = new DurableStub();
    $this->app->bind(Durable::class, fn () => $this->durable);
}

But when I run tests, it still uses Durable instead of DurableStub. If I change onShopSaved in the subscriber to use app()->get(Durable::class) instead of constructor injection, everything works fine. Sure, I can use app()->get(Durable::class), but it's a code smell. I'm trying to understand what the difference is here. Why does Laravel use a stub with app()->get(Durable::class) in the subscriber, but can't use a stub with constructor injection?
